# Is it possible to view the next line of a text file to search for a certain word but not actually proccess it?

Tags: php

I am writing a php script which reads lines from a text file to compose an email. Some of the lines begin with the following words:

> To:
>
> From: example@email.com
>
> example line, words words words... etc
>
> Subject:

When I read the line and find the word "From:", I want it to continue reading lines until it finds the word "Subject:". The issue I am having is that in order to check if the next line begins with "Subject:", I need to read the line with fgets(). But I don't want this to happen. If I find the word "Subject:" I wanted to not read the line, break (because I'm in a switch case), go to the beginning of the while loop again and THEN read the line that has "Subject:". I cannot think of a logical way to do this. I feel like I might have to use the goto function, but I understand that is poor practice. How can I get around this?

```
while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file, filesize("$filename"));
        if (!feof($file)) {
            $pos = strpos($line, ":");
            $lineMsg = substr($line, $pos + 2);
            switch(trim(strtolower(substr($line, 0, $pos + 2)))) {
            case("subject:"):
                if ($content[2][4] == 0) {
                    $content[0][4] = $lineMsg;
                    $content[1][4] = true;
                    $content[2][4] = 1;
                    }
                break;
            case("body:"):
                $content[0][5] .= $lineMsg;
                $content[1][5] = true;
                $content[2][5] = 1;
                $msg = fgets($file, filesize("$filename"));
                echo $msg;
                while (!feof($file) && compare($msg)) {
                    if (compare($msg)) {
                        $content[0][5] .= $msg;
                        echo $content[0][5] .= PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                    $msg = fgets($file, filesize("$filename"));
                } // end while loop
                if (!compare($msg)) {
                    break;
                }
                break 2;
```

(The rest of the switch case above is irrelevent to the problem)
Here is the compare() function:

```
function compare($msg) {
    if ((stripos($msg, "to:") !== false) || (stripos(strtolower($msg), "from:") !== false) || (stripos($msg, "cc:") !== $
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    } // end if-else statement
} // end compare function
```

I know there is a much easier way of doing the compare() function but for testing purposes and clarity I used the following above.

Any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are relatively small (10's of MB or less), I'd just use `file()` to read the entire content into an array http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Then you can access any line you want and loop over it like any array.

Answer (score -2):

checkout this: http://php.net/manual/de/function.fgets.php

this should be exactly what u looked for. it reads a file line by line.